# Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

Im writing a code for grocery store inventory that accepts input takes the quantity and prices calculates the value and stops after user enters 0 but when I compile after I enter the first number its say "segmentation fault". How would I fix that?

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define MAX 100

void show();

int main(void){

long long Barcode[MAX];
int Quantity[MAX], i, k, Counter;
float Price[MAX], Value[MAX], Total;

Counter=0;

show();

do {

  printf("Barcode : ",i);
  scanf("%lld", &Barcode[i]);

  printf("Price : ",i);
  scanf(" %f",&Price[i]);

  printf("Quantity: ",i);
  scanf(" %d",&Quantity[i]);

  Counter++;

  } while (Barcode !=0 && Counter !=MAX);

  for(i=0; i<Counter; i++) {

  Value[i] = (Quantity[i] * Price[i]);
 }
 printf("                 Goods In Stock               ");

 printf("Barcode           Price       Quantity    Value");
 printf("\n----------------------------------------------\n");

 for(k=0; k<Counter; k++) {

 printf("%-10lld",Barcode[k]);
 printf("%5.2f",Price[k]);
 printf("%8d",Quantity[k]);
 printf("%5f",Value[k]);
 }

 printf("%8c------",' ');
 printf("\nTotal Value of goods in stock ");

return 0;

}

void show() {

 printf("Grocery Store Inventory ");
 printf("\n-----------------------\n");

}
```

Comment: What's the value of `i`?

Comment: **i** is not initialised.

Comment: Initialize `i` to zero. That might change a few things.

Answer (score 2):

Try to always initialize your variables (unless you know what you are doing):

```
long long Barcode[MAX];
int Quantity[MAX], i=0, k=0, Counter=0;
float Price[MAX], Value[MAX], Total=0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You invoked *undefined behavior* by using value of uninitialized variable `i`  having automatic storage duration, which is indeterminate.

This part of your code

```
do {

  printf("Barcode : ",i);
  scanf("%lld", &Barcode[i]);

  printf("Price : ",i);
  scanf(" %f",&Price[i]);

  printf("Quantity: ",i);
  scanf(" %d",&Quantity[i]);

  Counter++;

  } while (Barcode !=0 && Counter !=MAX);
```

should be

```
do {
  i = Counter; /* assign Counter to i, so that i used here will have the correct value */
  printf("Barcode : ",i);
  scanf("%lld", &Barcode[i]);

  printf("Price : ",i);
  scanf(" %f",&Price[i]);

  printf("Quantity: ",i);
  scanf(" %d",&Quantity[i]);

  Counter++;

  /* Barcode != 0 will be alway true. Do you mean Barcode[i] != 0 ? */
  /* Note that using Barcode[Counter] != 0 is wrong here because Counter is incremented
   * and Barcode[Counter] will be uninitialized or out-of-range */
} while ( Barcode[i] != 0 && Counter !=MAX);
```